# 1 Texture For Multiple Models, Or 1 Model Using Different Textures For Each

Tags: unity

I'm creating some voxel flowers that are exactly the same, just different colours.  Is it better to create 5 models and use 1 texture that has the 5 different colours, or create 1 model and use 5 different textures for each colour?

Am curious as to which is more efficient in regards to performance, as there could be quite a few flowers on screen.

I'm playing around with MagicaVoxel and Unity.

[image: Flower]
[image: Flower 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one model with one texture.

Create a separate material for each flower-type. Each material uses the same texture but has a different color in its properties. This will require a shader which applies the albedo color only to specific pixels of the texture. You would have to do some shader programming for this. When you aren't into shader programming and want to use the premade Unity shader instead, you can create a model with two materials. Use one material for the recolorable polygons and one for those which are not recolorable. You can then assign the Unity standard shader to both materials and set the albedo color on the material for the recolorable parts.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't know I could do that in Unity with 1 model.  Basically I took the flower into Blender, assigned separate materials, exported as FBX, and Unity picked up the separate materials automatically, and as you said, changing the albedo colour lets me recolour parts of the flower.  Thanks a lot.